# SQL queries for getting some product info

Tags: sql

```
select * 
from suMain
where trackingMonth = '2018-07'
  and shopID = '421'
  and productName like '%a'
  and productName like '%x'
order by productName
```

This query is not working for me. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: That's not java code, what type of SQL database are you using?

Comment: You want both conditions to be satisfied with an one row? or else either of conditions to be satisfied with one row?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?"  Do you get an error message?  What error message?  Do you see rows that you're not expecting to see?  Do you *not* see rows that you *are* expecting to see?  Be specific.

Comment: And on the off chance that it's not just a transcription error, you're missing an opening single-quote `'` character in `like '%x'`

Comment: if i remove one like '%a' then i have the output. but if i use both like then there is no output

Comment: I want both conditions to be satisfied in one row

Comment: @Manoj Think about your logic.  `productname like '%a' and productName like '%x'`.  Do you think you can get a result from this statement????  ProductName can only end with either 'a' or 'x', not both.

Comment: @Manoj - Seems your requirement is not clear. You should try to explain in plain English what you are trying to achieve. 
`productName like '%a'` means ends with letter a
`productName like %x'` means ends with letter x
Logically, you cannot satisfy both the conditions. 
You product name will end with some letter. It could be a or x. But it cannot be both. 
So when you remove `and productName like '%a'`, it works as you have got one or more products ending with letter x.

Comment: there are products wchich ends with a and x and both under this shopID and TrackingMonth

Comment: if i says productname not like '%a' and productName not like '%x' this shows the correct output

Comment: "*there are products wchich ends with a and x*" - that's impossible. There can only be one single character at the end. Or do you mean `%ax`?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
select * 
from suMain
where trackingMonth = '2018-07'
  and shopID = '421'
  and (productName like '%a'
  or productName like '%x')
order by productName
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Manoj - Glad to know that it works for you, please mark my answer as correct answer.